# How (without libraries) can I get the public address from a private key?

Tags: addresses, private-key

I want to know a way to know the public address used for funds transfer from the private key. (As myetherwallet do when you get your wallet info by entering your private key)

I don't care with wich programming language (even if I prefer javascript, if it's possible).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to write this without using a library? It's practically impossible to do cryptographic stuff securely, even *with* a background in cryptography.

You have been warned. But to give you as little rope to hang yourself as possible, all you have to do is reimplement a couple of functions described in [this blog post](https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address/.). It's up to you to figure out how far you want to go to eliminate libraries (write your own bignum library? Write your program to run in baremetal assembly to avoid using possibly compromised OS libraries?) You can also look at the code used to implement the functionality in a library. Everything you need for Python [is open source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/69qfkv/python_script_that_converts_ethereum_private_key/?st=j7zilw60&sh=74f47522).

Comment: It's mostly for educationnal purpose. I won't implement it anywhere but in a test environment.

Answer (score 2):

As was said by @lungj it is really not a good idea not to use libraries. Because you need to use elliptic curve cryptography, which rellies heavily on mathematical properties. Also you will need sha3 for hashing.

If you can use the libraries [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic) for elliptic curve cryptography and [js-sha3](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3) for sha3 hashing, here's a short example

```
const assert = require('assert');
const EC = require('elliptic').ec;
const keccak256 = require('js-sha3').keccak256;

async function main() {
  try {
    const ec = new EC('secp256k1');

    const key = ec.keyFromPrivate('208065a247edbe5df4d86fbdc0171303f23a76961be9f6013850dd2bdc759bbb', 'hex');

    const privateKey = key.getPrivate();
    const publicKey = key.getPublic().encode('hex').slice(2);
    assert.equal(publicKey, '836b35a026743e823a90a0ee3b91bf615c6a757e2b60b9e1dc1826fd0dd16106f7bc1e8179f665015f43c6c81f39062fc2086ed849625c06e04697698b21855e');

    const address = keccak256(Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex')).slice(64 - 40);
    assert.equal(address, '0bed7abd61247635c1973eb38474a2516ed1d884');

    console.log(`Private Key: 0x${privateKey}`);
    console.log(`Public Key: 0x${publicKey}`);
    console.log(`Address: 0x${address.toString()}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

main();
```

Should output

> Private Key: 0x14700869030423518308970518253936238282279417230371408086143856620903190600635
>
> Public Key: 0x836b35a026743e823a90a0ee3b91bf615c6a757e2b60b9e1dc1826fd0dd16106f7bc1e8179f665015f43c6c81f39062fc2086ed849625c06e04697698b21855e
>
> Address: 0x0bed7abd61247635c1973eb38474a2516ed1d884

Comment: Your try-catch block around main() won't catch any errors, because if main has an error, it will just return a promise that rejects. Instead of the try-catch block, you should use this: `main().catch(err => { console.error(err); });`

Comment: You are right, the try/catch should be inside `main()`.