# Why HD wallet instance returns two xpub-xpriv key pairs inside Root and HDKey?

Tags: addresses, private-key, public-key, hd-wallets, recovery

I have implemented address generation using HDWallet as shown in the snippet below:

```js
let Seed = generateMnemonic();
const wallet = EthHdWallet.fromMnemonic(Seed);
console.log("Wallet" + JSON.stringify(wallet));
console.log(typeof wallet);
let address = wallet.generateAddresses(3);
console.log("Wallet after address generation: " + JSON.stringify(wallet));
console.log("Address generated: " + address);
```

Wallet gives one object which contains:

- `_hdKey` (Has parameter `_hdKey` which further have two parameter `xpriv` & `xpub` )
- `_root` (Also Has parameter `_hdKey` which further have two parameter `xpriv` & `xpub` different from hd key's parameter value)
- `_children` (Generated addresses with its own private and public key pairs)

Difficulty about:

1. What does that two key pairs indicates? which we get it under the `_hdKey` and `_root`?
2. How to recover my address only using privateKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to check [BIP 32 documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki), the objects you are looking at can be traced to concepts from the specification.

The underscore may indicate that they are an implementation detail of EthHdWallet so for a detailed answer someone will have to look at the source code.

From the [EthHdWallet's constructor](https://github.com/meth/eth-hd-wallet/blob/master/src/index.js#L48-L52) we can determine the meaning:

```
  constructor (xPrivKey) {
    this._hdKey = fromExtendedKey(xPrivKey)
    this._root = this._hdKey.derivePath(BIP44_PATH)
    this._children = []
  }
```

- **_hdKey** Is the master node for the HD wallet
- **_root** Is the node at Ethereum derivation path `m/44'/60'/0'/0`
- **_children** Children keys derived from _root

It is possible to calculate address from private key (see for example
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27187), but it involves some low level calculation. An easier solution is to use a library like https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet and 
import the private key into a wallet and obtain the address.

```
const wallet = HDWallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer)
const address = wallet.getChecksumAddressString()
```

Comment: thank you for perfect and simple explanation, From the EthHDWallet constructor, everything has cleared.! As you've said that we can get our address back by using private key. But I would like to ask that is that possible using Seed to?

Comment: @Rudrika EthHdWallet have a function `getAddresses()` that returns all addresses previously generated. For Ethereum you can use the first one.